# Single Sign On for intranet with Apache and Linux MIT Kerberos

Tags: apache-2.2, active-directory, kerberos, single-sign-on, mitkerberos

**EDIT: SOLVED! See my answer below.**

Greetings, I am looking for a way to do a single sign on to an intranet in the following manner:

1. A Linux user logs on via a graphical frontend (for example, GNOME).
2. He automatically requests a TGT for his username from the MIT Kerberos KDC.
3. **Via some way or another, the Apache server (which we'll assume is on the same server as the KDC), is informed that this user has logged in.**
4. When the user accesses the intranet, he is automatically granted access to his web applications.

I don't think I've seen this kind of functionality while searching the net. I know the following possibilities exist:

- Using an authentication module such as mod_auth_kerb, a user is presented with a login prompt to enter his username and password, which are then authenticated against the MIT Kerberos server. **(I would like this to be automatic.)**
- IIS supports integrated Windows logon via ASP.Net when the user is part of an Active Directory. **(I'm looking for the Linux / Apache equivalent.)**

Any suggestions, criticism and ideas are highly appreciated. This is for a school project to show a proof-of-concept, so every handy piece of information is more than welcome. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it!

I followed the instructions on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SingleSignOn (See: "Application Installation") to configure the Apache webserver.

Here is my httpd.conf [[IMAGE]](http://img295.imageshack.us/img295/6272/screenshothttpdconfetca.png):

> ServerName www.eindwerk.lan
>
> < Directory /var/www/ >
>          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
>
> ```
>    AllowOverride None
>    Order allow,deny
>    allow from all
>
>   AuthType Kerberos
> ```
>
> KrbMethodNegotiate on
>
> KrbMethodK5Passwd on
>
> ```
>   AuthName "Kerberos Login"
>   KrbAuthRealm EINDWERK.LAN
>   Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/auth/apache2.keytab
>   require valid-user
> ```
>
> < /Directory >

1. Then, I configured Mozilla Firefox to trust my internal site (www.eindwerk.lan) [[IMAGE]](http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/623/screenshotaboutconfigmo.png):

   network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris : eindwerk.lan

   network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris: eindwerk.lan
2. Do a `kinit` in a terminal. [[IMAGE]](http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/6048/screenshotbeerendubuntu.png)
3. Browse to the internal site: **You are now automatically logged in!**

   How does this work?

   - Mozilla Firefox does a regular HTTP/GET request.
   - Apache replies with HTTP/401 Authorization Required.
   - Mozilla Firefox replies with the Kerberos token we just got with `kinit`. [[IMAGE OF WIRESHARK CAPTURE]](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/78/screenshotlocapturingwi.png)
   - Kerberos authentication occurs, and Apache replies with HTTP/200 OK.
4. Do a `klist` in a terminal. You should see the ticket for the webserver! [[IMAGE]](http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/6048/screenshotbeerendubuntu.png)
5. Do a `kdestroy` in a terminal. [[IMAGE]](http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/6048/screenshotbeerendubuntu.png)
6. Hard refresh (CTRL+F5) the internal site. You are now presented with a login prompt! [[IMAGE]](http://img80.imageshack.us/img80/4038/screenshotauthenticatio.png)